# form to normal text using CSS and minimal jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form having all kind of tags (check box, dropdown etc) in my HTML page, on click of a button I want to show the same form as a normal text on the popup. For popup, I am using jQuery dialog.

using following code, I am able to show the same form on the popup. but it is coming as a form with editable fields.

```
var dialogHtml = jQuery('#requestForm').html();
            jQuery(dialogHtml).dialog();
```

is it possible to change the same form in non-editable text format on the popup. I don't want to write the same code for the popup.

Actually, requirement is like that, I have a form which needs to be filled and on submitting of that form, I need to display order number along with that form's data. OrderNumber + some other HTML data I am getting dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal text popup"? And why show the same form twice?

Comment: Is the requirement to show some sort of 'confirmation'? If so, then you want to send this data to the server first, then return it formatted to ensure that they are confirming what is actually sent to the server. You state that 'on submitting' which it sounds like you haven't actually yet done.

Comment: (In other words, can you share the requirements in terms of user-flow/user-needs rather than solutioning? There may be a more appropriate solution)

Comment: yes @DA. it is an order confirmation message. Requirement is: we need to submit one request form and in return one confirmation message will get displayed with some order number and date and form data. You are correct I should collect all the submitted data from the server and should display it. but I don't want to write same HTML code in my php file and html file. That's why I was doing it like thi. if you have any better idea, please let me know

Comment: @user1653773 I'm not sure I entirely follow. Are you saying you are taking the form data, submitting it to the server, and then want to return the form data for confirmation, but don't want to write any new PHP to reformat it and instead want to use the initial form markup? If so, I'd encourage you to rethink that if I can. Just from a user experience standpoint, the user doesn't want to see the 'form' at this point...they want to see the 'receipt' to confirm yes, that's what they want.

Comment: yes @DA, you are absolutely correct, I want to display a receipt only. which have all the data from the FORM + order number. That's why I wrote, I need that FORM data in normal text form without any text box or dropdown, it should look like a receipt. So instead of printing that receipt in server side, I can copy my existing form and display that. Idea behind it that, if tomorrow I want to change any label, I don't have to search that same label in my server code also. or if I have to apply internationalization on my form, in that case I need to just concentrate on my HTMLs.

Comment: I guess I see this more as a server-side issue rather than client side JS/HTML. What format is the data being returned as? It sounds like the data is being returned with the full form HTML markup?

Comment: returning data is in HTML format i.e. $orderConfirmationMessage = '
   <div>
    <h2> Order Number :  '.$orderId.'</h2><br>
    <h2> Date : '.$today_date.'</h2><br><br>
   </div>
   ';

Comment: only above data I am returning from the server rest of the form should be picked from the front end only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this, which loops through all the form elements, and put their names and values into a table for display.

```
var dialogHtml = $("<table></table>");
jQuery('#requestForm').find("input,select,textarea").each( function(){
    results.append( "<tr><td>" + $(this).attr("name") + ":</td><td>" + $(this).val() + "</td></tr>");
});

jQuery(dialogHtml).dialog();
```

Comment: you solution in really good. but it has few problems: 1. my form has "datatable" also, above code is not handling that. I don't know, how to handle it with above logic. 2. "option" button both are coming selected and unselected both.in that case I don't want to display value, I want to display that option label  only 3. for all the tags we have some label so instead of "name" I want to display corresponding label value. <label for="details">Details *</label><textarea  type="text" id="details" name="details" maxlength="50" size="30"></textarea> like this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Set the `disabled` property for all new fields.

```
var dialogHtml = jQuery('#requestForm').clone(); // must use clone() here
dialogHtml.find("input").attr( "disabled", "disabled");
jQuery(dialogHtml).dialog();
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tH8yv/

Comment: Good point! There may be a better method then, something like `$("#requestForm").appendTo("#dialog");` to move into the dialog, and then move back upon dialog close if necessary. That's a lot of extra overhead to apply checked values, selected values, etc.

Comment: clone() is a good idea. but I have some dynamic HTML which needs to be appended with the existing form. how can I do it?

Comment: You can use `dialogHtml` variable to anchor to, like: `dialogHtml.append("<p>Some new elements here</p>"); $("<p>Something else</p>").insertAfter( dialogHtml.find("input:first") );`

Comment: I think text area value is getting lost when I am using clone(). is it jquery issue or my code issue..any idea?

Comment: It is .clone() issue almost certainly. I am going to post another answer which I think may be more relevant given your edits.